# Is there a way to reorder the fields in an export mapping?

Tags: export, field-mapping

I had a request to reorder the fields in an export mapping that had been created previously. Is there a way to do this via the UI? And if not, is it kosher to manually edit the `column_number` in the `civicrm_mapping_field` table, or could that produce unexpected results somehow? (I am assuming that is what determines the sort order, so please correct me if that assumption is wrong!)

Answer (score 1):

Laryn -

I don't think there's a way in the UI to update the order... I would suggest creating a small mapping and reordering it in the database (I agree that the column_number is the likely candidate - interesting that it's not weight as in so many other Civi features) to confirm that will work.

Lesley

Answer (score 1):

This is coming thanks to the work being done on the Form Builder

https://civicrm.org/blog/josh/improvements-to-the-export-interface-are-in-the-works